# How to use correctly CheckBox in CustomListview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I have a custom listview with [PICTURE] - [TEXT] - [CHECKBOX]
When I select a checkbox and I like to scroll down, there are more checkbox selected.
Why is that so? And how can I fix this issue?

-> I just select ONE checkbox
-> Then I scoll down and there are more checkbox selected

[image]
[image]
Best regards
MSeiz5

My CustomAdapter_

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
            TextView rawTextView;

            boolean[] checkBoxState;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;   
            ListContent holder;
            private ArrayList<Notification> arrNotification=null;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrlist) {

        arrNotification = new ArrayList<Notification>();

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(connected_upload.this);
        checkBoxState=new boolean[arrNotification.size()];            
        this.arrlist = arrlist;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrlist.size();
    }

    public int getCount2()
    {
        return arrNotification.size();      
    }

    public Object getItem2(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId2(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.connected_upload, null);
        holder=new ListContent();
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.checkBox1 );


        convertView.setTag(holder);

        if(convertView == null){
            // LayoutInflater class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.connected_upload_row, null);

            holder=new ListContent();
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.checkBox1 );

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
                   // R.id.img_list, R.id.string_cell
                     maptemp=new HashMap<String, String>();
                     maptemp=arrlist.get(position);
        rawTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.string_cell);
        rawTextView.setText(maptemp.get("string_cell"));


            if (isfolder == true){
                imgview=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_list);
                imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);

            } else {


                    Bitmap test = getbitpam(maptemp.get("img_list"));
                    imgview=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_list);

                    imgview.setImageBitmap(test); 

                    System.gc();

            }
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


}
```

LogCat:

```
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at mseiz.freeftp.connected_upload$CustomAdapter.getView(connected_upload.java:306)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2361)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5057)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15481)
01-16 13:41:05.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(V
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with CheckBox inside ListView is that the view gets recycled due to recycling of ListView and the value of Checkbox(check or uncheck) is not maintained. To, maintain the state to CheckBox there has to be something that can store the state of Checkbox.

Refer this [Link](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html).It has well explained example.

```
 public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
            private boolean[] checkBoxState;
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
            private ListContent holder;
            private ArrayList<Notification> arrNotification=null;
            public ListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notification> notify)
            {     
                arrNotification = new ArrayList<Notification>();

                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                checkBoxState=new boolean[arrNotification.size()];
                imageLoader=new ImageLoader(NotificationListActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
            }
            public int getCount()
            {
                return arrNotification.size();      
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) 
            {
                return position;
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) 
            {
                return position;
            }
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (convertView == null) 
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.noti_list, null);
                    holder=new ListContent();
                    holder.entity_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.entityname_textview);
                    holder.noti_thumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_noti_thumb);
                    holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.CheckBox01 );

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } 
                else
                {
                    holder = (ListContent)convertView.getTag();
                }           

                holder.noti_thumb.setTag(arrNotification.get(position).thumbnail);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrNotification.get(position).thumbnail,NotificationListActivity.this, holder.noti_thumb);

                holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

                holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                        {
                            checkBoxState[position]=true;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            checkBoxState[position]=false;


                        }
                    }
                });


                holder.checkbox.setTag(position);

                return convertView; 
            }
        }

        class ListContent 
        {
            TextView entity_type;
            TextView content_type;
            ImageView noti_thumb;
            CheckBox checkbox;
        }
```

Comment: I don't get it... Its to complicate for me

Comment: What he said, is to do something like I did in my example

Comment: @MarcoSeiz For your easy understanding,i have added simple adapter which has listitem as image,checkbox,textview. check it :)

Comment: yes,what you need to add is the checkbox array and its setOnClickListener. Try this :)

Comment: @MarcoSeiz if my answer helpful to you,don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: Hmmm I added the code but it crashes.. Take a look to my logcat message in the question and my new code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it may help you.

```
mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(mSplitActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mStrings));
        mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Also try this
http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html

Comment: With CHOID_MODE_MULTIPLE I can't select an item on my listview... And when I select the checkbox the problem still exists... I add a screenshot to my question...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tag of your checkboxes and check the tag while setting the value of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

What I did:

In my Object, I put and `boolean id_selected` and in my CustomAdapter, I check if the object is selected (then I check the checbox) or not, and in `getView` I disable the checkbox clickable, and in the `convertview` click I invert the `id_selected` and refresh the CheckBox. With this when the user click in the checkbox or in the line, they check or uncheck the checkbox and can do what you want...

Here is an example:

```
            final T t = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
            }

            final View vv = convertView;

            convertView.setClickable(true);
            convertView.setFocusable(true);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_background);

                  TextView tv_ds_lista          = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ds_lista);
            final CheckBox chkbx_id_selecionado = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_selecionado);

            chkbx_id_selecionado.setClickable(false);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {    
                        chkbx_id_selecionado.setChecked(!chkbx_id_selecionado.isChecked());

                    t.setId_selecionado(chkbx_id_selecionado.isChecked());

                }
            });

            tv_ds_lista.setText(t.toString());

            return convertView;
```

I modified some of my class, but the essence is in there... In my original class I use reflection and other specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> recIdArr = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> selectedIds = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> reportslist;
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
  View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  CheckBox cBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cb1);

  if(cBox.isChecked())
  {
    selectedIds.add(recIdArr.get(reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox)));    
  }
  else
  {
    selectedIds.remove(recIdArr.get(reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must store the state of items using custom Adapter like the following example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {
// MyClass has a field named 'selected'

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView;
        final MyClass item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflator.inflate(rsc, null);
        } else {
            rowView = (View) convertView;
        }

       //...
       CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
       chkSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                item.selected = isChecked;
            }
        });
        chkSelected.setChecked(item.selected);

        //...
     }

}
```